# Cannot deploy python with webapp to azure on python 3.8

Tags: python, azure, flask, web-deployment, azure-cli

I am trying to deploy a test project using the `Flask` framework into the azure cloud using the `Azure CLI`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python

There are some issues regarding the `runtime_version` of my app. Everytime I try to run the command for deploying it tries to upgrade the runtime_version to the `python|3.7` even if I set it to the `python|3.8` in the settings and then the deployment fails. It has to be set to `python|3.7` to be succesfully deployed.

The **app** is quite simple:

```
from flask import Flask
from markupsafe import escape

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index page'

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!!!'

@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return 'User %s' % escape(username)

@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def show_post(post_id):
    # show the post with the given id, the id is an int
    return 'Post %d' % post_id

@app.route('/path/<path:subpath>')
def show_subpath(subpath):
    # show the subpath after /path/
    return 'Subpath %s' % escape(subpath)

@app.route('/projects/')
def projects():
    return 'The project page'

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'The about page'
```

I also created a **requirements.txt** file with the required packages as recommended in the microsoft documentation.

```
click==7.1.2
flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jinja2==2.11.2
markupsafe==1.1.1
werkzeug==1.0.1
```

And this is the command I used to deploy the application the first time

> az webapp up --sku F1 -l westeurope -n XXXXXX-blf

**Output:**

```
(venv) D:\dev\FlaskTesting [master ≡ +4 ~0 -1 !]> az webapp up --sku F1 -l westeurope -n XXXXXX-blf
webapp XXXXXX-blf doesn't exist
Creating Resource group 'InsaneSpeech_rg_Linux_westeurope' ...
Resource group creation complete
Creating AppServicePlan 'InsaneSpeech_asp_Linux_westeurope_0' ...
Creating webapp 'XXXXXX-blf' ...
Creating zip with contents of dir D:\dev\FlaskTesting ...
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
You can launch the app at http://XXXXXX-blf.azurewebsites.net
{
  "URL": "http://XXXXXX-blf.azurewebsites.net",
  "appserviceplan": "InsaneSpeech_asp_Linux_westeurope_0",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "name": "XXXXXX-blf",
  "os": "Linux",
  "resourcegroup": "InsaneSpeech_rg_Linux_westeurope",
  "runtime_version": "python|3.7",
  "runtime_version_detected": "-",
  "src_path": "D:\\dev\\FlaskTesting"
}
```

Then I go to the azure portal and try to change the `Stack settings` to target `Python 3.8` under `XXXXXX-blf -> Settings -> Configuration -> General settings -> Stack | Major version / Minor version`
After clicking save I try to run again the command to update my code

> az webapp up -n python-blf

But this time the output shows an error:

```
Webapp XXXXXX-blf already exists. The command will deploy contents to the existing app.
Updating runtime version from PYTHON|3.8 to python|3.7
Creating zip with contents of dir D:\dev\FlaskTesting ...
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
Zip deployment failed. {'id': 'd9ff6c84c00844bf9f988bd4c98c81d6', 'status': 3, 'status_text': '', 
'author_email': 'N/A', 'author': 'N/A', 'deployer': 'Push-Deployer', 'message': 'Created via a push deployment', 
'progress': '', 'received_time': '2020-07-05T09:10:02.1802651Z', 'start_time': '2020-07-05T09:10:02.3953194Z', 
'end_time': '2020-07-05T09:10:18.7991349Z', 
'last_success_end_time': None, 'complete': True, 'active': False, 'is_temp': False, 'is_readonly': True, 
'url': 'https://XXXXXX-blf.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 
'log_url': 'https://XXXXXX-blf.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 'site_name': 'XXXXXX-blf'}. 
Please run the command az webapp log deployment show
                           -n XXXXXX-blf -g InsaneSpeech_rg_Linux_westeurope
```

I check the log url and this is the issue:

```
{
   "ClassName":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
   "Message":"No log found for 'latest'.",
   "Data":null,
   "InnerException":null,
   "HelpURL":null,
   "StackTraceString":"   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.GetLogEntries(String id) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Core/Deployment/DeploymentManager.cs:line 111\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.DeploymentController.GetLogEntry(String id) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services/Deployment/DeploymentController.cs:line 432",
   "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
   "RemoteStackIndex":0,
   "ExceptionMethod":null,
   "HResult":-2147024894,
   "Source":"Kudu.Core",
   "WatsonBuckets":null,
   "FileNotFound_FileName":null,
   "FileNotFound_FusionLog":null
}
```

After this issue, without changing anything I can run the same command again and get a correct deployment but with `python|3.7` ...

```
(venv) D:\dev\FlaskTesting [master ≡ +5 ~0 -1 !]> az webapp up -n XXXXXX-blf
Webapp XXXXXX-blf already exists. The command will deploy contents to the existing app.
Creating zip with contents of dir D:\dev\FlaskTesting ...
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
You can launch the app at http://XXXXXX-blf.azurewebsites.net
{
  "URL": "http://XXXXXX-blf.azurewebsites.net",
  "appserviceplan": "InsaneSpeech_asp_Linux_westeurope_0",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "name": "XXXXXX-blf",
  "os": "Linux",
  "resourcegroup": "InsaneSpeech_rg_Linux_westeurope",
  "runtime_version": "python|3.7",
  "runtime_version_detected": "-",
  "sku": "FREE",
  "src_path": "D:\\dev\\FlaskTesting"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have configured the CI\CD in azure linked to my github repository and the github actions do deploy on push with my webapp running python 3.8

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - XXXXXX-blf

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Python version
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: '3.8'

    - name: Build using AppService-Build
      uses: azure/appservice-build@v1
      with:
        platform: python
        platform-version: '3.8'

    - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v1
      with:
        app-name: 'XXXXXX-blf'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX }}
```

Any idea?

Comment: did you install those dependencies

Comment: yes, they are listed in the requirements.txt file within the project folder and the first deployment works. I get the error after switching the python runtime version.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-web-app?tabs=cmd

Comment: @Sajeetharan I know... the required packages are installed I have checked using the SSH console and I can verify the packages are installed and the python version is the 3.8. The problem is I cannot deploy targeting python 3.8. It automatically changes it to 3.7

Comment: no what version did you create your web app  with?

Comment: The app was created with the 3.8.3. that's the only python version I have in my dev environment. But when I ran the az webapp up it always create a webapp with 3.7

Comment: have exactly the same problem - created a webapp with runtime python|3.7 and it rolls it back no matter what

Comment: May I ask if there is a better answer to this question. Does the official Microsoft reply? I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your description and the tutorial provided, I also found this problem. And in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-up), the parameters of the `az webapp up` command do not support the specified python version.

If you must use the `az webapp up` command, it should not be possible at present. I think this is a bug, you can `raise a support ticket` on the portal to confirm.

I give an alternative solution, you can use [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment). You can use `git`. If the code is confidential, you can also use your own to create a git storage service locally and use [local git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git) for deployment. In this case, the application will be automatically deployed after each modification is submitted.

Comment: thanks for answering. I submitted a ticket for the KuDu team. At this moment, this is a bug. As you can see in the updated question, the workaround with CI\CD was already done. That worked without issues.