# Gitlab CI/CD and Azure deploying Django

Tags: django, azure, gitlab, azure-web-app-service

Am trying to deploy Django code to Webapp using gitlab CI, here's the .gitlab-ci.yml ;

```
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.25.4
  entrypoint: [""]

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

stages:
  - deploy

deploy-azure-stag:
  stage: deploy
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  script:
    - echo "Logging into Azure"
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    - echo "Deploying to Azure App Service"
    - az webapp up --name $AZURE_APP_NAME
```

However am getting this error, how best can I continuously deploy my Django code .

**Error am getting.**

Deploying to Azure App Service

```
$ az webapp up --name $AZURE_APP_NAME
WARNING: Webapp 'app_name' already exists. The command will deploy contents to the existing app.
ERROR: Unable to retrieve details of the existing app 'app_name'. Please check that the app is a part of the current subscription if updating an existing app. If creating a new app, app names must be globally unique. Please try a more unique name or leave unspecified to receive a randomly generated name.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

- The error code you are receiving is due to the az web app command not able to recognize your Web app that is deployed on Azure.
- You can refer this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739006/cannot-deploy-python-with-webapp-to-azure-on-python-3-8) by Jason pan for the insight on the command.
- Make sure the Azure Client ID and Client Secret that you're using in Gitlab variables have contributor role assigned on the Azure web app for it to access the web app after az login.

***As a workaround, You can refer this [**Blog**](https://rlaput.github.io/Azure-GitLab-Autodeploy/#)*** :-

1. ***In your existing Web app visit > Advanced tools > Go > [xxxxxwebapp32.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1](https://xxxxbapp32.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1)***

And **Copy the ssh key** like below:-

[image]

2. ***Gitlab > left section > Settings > Repository > Deploy keys > Expand > copy the ssh key like below***

[image]

3. Now visit your ***Azure Web app > Deployment > Deployment Center > Select External git and copy the Gitlab python repository clone URL and add the branch name > Save the settings and your Deployment will be started and succeed like below:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Python web app deployed successfully.

Python web app code [reference](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart)

[image]